# Display an array at the bottom of its container (ScrollView)

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, jsx

I have a list and I want to position that at the bottom of its container. I thought I could do that with flex-end (yeah, I also tried `contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: "flex-end",}}` for ScrollView), but somehow it doesn't work. Maybe because of ScrollView, I don't know. The code below is the simplified version of what I've done. So, I'd like to keep the hierarchy as it is. Is there a way to display that array starting from bottom?

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView, Dimensions} from 'react-native';


const WindowsWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width 
const WindowsHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height 

export default function ExampleComponent ({navigation}){
    const ownedAudios=["First item", "Second item", "Third item", "Fourth item"]
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.recordingsList}>
                <ScrollView>
                    {ownedAudios? ownedAudios.map((key, index)=>{
                    return (
                        <View key={index} onTouchEnd={() => console.log("heyhey")}>
                            <Text style={{color:"#474131", fontSize:14, fontWeight:"400", }}>{key}</Text>
                        </View>
                    );
                    }):<></>}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
} 


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#0C0A09",
        color: "#c6825a",
        zIndex: 0,
        flex: 1, 
        justifyContent: 'center', 
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    recordingsList: {
        flex:1, 
        justifyContent: 'flex-end', 
        alignItems: 'flex-start',  
        position: "absolute", 
        width: WindowsWidth-130,    
        height: WindowsHeight - 260, 
        left:0, 
        bottom:355, 
        padding:15,
        paddingLeft:0,
        top:170,
        backgroundColor:"pink",
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flexGrow: 1` and `flexShrink: 1` will do the job for you,

[image]

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const WindowsWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const WindowsHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default function App() {
  const ownedAudios = [
    'First item',
    'Second item',
    'Third item',
    'Fourth item',
  ];
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.recordingsList}>
        <View style={styles.spacer} />
        <View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
          <ScrollView>
            {ownedAudios ? (
              ownedAudios.map((key, index) => {
                return (
                  <View key={index} onTouchEnd={() => console.log('heyhey')}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: '#474131',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: '400',
                      }}>
                      {key}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                );
              })
            ) : (
              <></>
            )}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#0C0A09',
    color: '#c6825a',
    flex: 1,
  },
  recordingsList: {
    width: WindowsWidth,
    height: WindowsHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  },
  spacer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    flexShrink: 1,
  },
});
```